# Keras Dense Layer Dimension Issues

Tags: keras, nlp

Currently the goal of my task is to be able to, given input of two sentences, 
output two labelings of the phrasal-synonyms of the two sentences.
e.g. I am [happy], I am [having a good time]

However, I can never get my dense layer to output the dimension I want, which is [batch size, max_sentence_length, num_classes].

I've looked at some other posts saying that dense layer only allows the "units" parameter to be 1-D, so I should flatten my labels before I get it through the dense layer, and reshape my label matrix accordingly for loss function calculation, but I don't know if this is actually the appropriate way to approach it.

My current model is something like this:

Two inputs: (None, 58)
GLoVE embedding: (None, 58, 300)
BiLSTM (without return sequences): (None, 256)
Dense: (None, 290)

I've tried getting this to run too, but the performance is abysmal so I am questioning myself if I did anything incorrectly...

My intended result was originally to have the dense layer output dimension (None, 58, 5), as I have sentence length 58 and 5 different labels, thus the 290 in dense: 58*5=290.

Comment: For this you simply have to use recurrent layers, not dense layers. Please include full code.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but eventually I added Time Distributed to my dense layer for an extra dimension, and it's working pretty well for me.